# Install XGBoost for Java - Mac

Tags: java, maven, jvm, sbt, xgboost

I need to load a saved XGBoost model in Java.
**TLDR:** How do I install XGBoost for Java, the instructions on the documentation are not clear at all and I can't find any tutorial.

The [JVM installation guide for XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#jvm) has two headings `Maven` and `sbt`. This is the content below `Maven`:

```
<properties>
  ...
  <!-- Specify Scala version in package name -->
  <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>ml.dmlc</groupId>
      <artifactId>xgboost4j_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>latest_version_num</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>ml.dmlc</groupId>
      <artifactId>xgboost4j-spark_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>latest_version_num</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The following is the content below `sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "ml.dmlc" %% "xgboost4j" % "latest_version_num",
  "ml.dmlc" %% "xgboost4j-spark" % "latest_version_num"
)
```

I created a new project on IntelliJ, selected the build system Maven and pasted the content under the Maven heading into the project's POM but that just led to an error.
Do I also need to do something with SBT first?

**I also tried building from the source.** I downloaded the source code, ensured that JAVA_HOME was defined, moved to the jvm-packages directory and ran `mvn package` but I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:testCompile (test-compile) on project xgboost4j_2.12: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 240 (Exit value: 240) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

If anyone has any clue on how I can run XGBoost in Java, please do let me know?

Comment: You most likely should replace `latest_version_num` with the latest version number.

Comment: That's the SBT instruction. I didn't even try that, do I need to use sbt if I'm using maven?

Comment: The instructions appear to assume a more experienced reader than you.   I would suggest going back to the Maven build, double check that the latest version number is set correctly, do some experiments to see if you can make it work, and then show your pom.xml as well as whatever "that just led to an error. "  You are the only one who can see your screen - that information may be useful (and perhaps even indicate what should be done to fix it).